# how to create JAR File

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I know creating JAR files is easy, just use eclipse, right click on the project and select export and follow the wizard.

There is also another way that is command-line, we can use this command.

```
jar cf myjarfilename.jar file1.class file2.class
```

The problem is I cannot use use eclipse to create JAR because my code is compiled in separate projects and then I place .class files in a particular hierarchy, compiled 'em into a JAR and place 'em at a specific location from where my web-app uses it.

I could use the command line but that is not practical as my hierarchy is complex and uses a lot of .class files. (folders and only .class files)

Now I need to make a JAR out of it. How to.

Comment: You should use some build tool that manages complexity for you, look at maven

Comment: You could use an Ant script to automate the process

Comment: what if I user WinRAR, set the archive type to ZIP and compression type to Store which is zero compression. Then ZIP it and after wards change the extension from .ZIP to .JAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, making a .jar file is easy.

There are many alternatives.

1) Eclipse:
   Select project > Right-click, Export as, .jar

2) .bat file/shell script:

```
jar cf myjarfilename.jar file1.class file2.class
```

3) .bat file/shell script:

```
mkdir staging-directory
copy/s source-files staging-directory
jar cf myjarfilename.jar staging-directory
```

4) Write an [Ant build.xml](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) or [Maven pom.xml](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/) to automate your build (including generating your .jar file).

Here's a very good tutorial on Apache Ant/build.xml:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html

```
  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\de.vogella.build.test.ant.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

Comment: what if I user WinRAR, set the archive type to ZIP and compression type to Store which is zero compression. Then ZIP it and after wards change the extension from .ZIP to .JAR

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Eclipse does not have a command line interface allowing you to do the same things from a command line, as you can do inside Eclipse.

In my experience the most reliable approach is to learn Maven and then adapt your current code to Maven conventions (possibly split over several modules).  This has the added benefit of your project being usable in all the current three major IDE's instead of only Eclipse.

Comment: what if I user WinRAR, set the archive type to ZIP and compression type to Store which is zero compression. Then ZIP it and after wards change the extension from .ZIP to .JAR

Comment: You can.  You can also use the jar command in the JDK.  You will quickly find that this would be nice to automate.

Comment: could you post your comment as a reply so that I accept. Your "You can" led me to try it. Then I put the JAR file where it was supposed to be, then I tested my web-app running of web-sphere and it is working great