# How to run Java Program with packages included

Tags: java, package

I'm learning about Java packages. So far I know that packages are used to group similar classes. I'm familiar on how to create a new package on intellij but wanted to do all the work using command line i.e. compiling the [dot]java file in [dot] class file and then running the code using java command.

I wrote programs with first file as prog1.java and second file as prog2.java

prog1.java

```
public class prog1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is program 1");
    }
}
```

prog2.java

```
public class prog2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is program 2");
    }
}
```

Then I wrote the following commands in terminal

```
>javac prog1.java
>java prog1
>javac prog2.java
>java prog2
```

And got the desirable output. (Snip also attached)
[Clean scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGYsv.png)

But when I try to use the package concept i.e. I try to include all the byte code files in package called programmes I'm getting error.

prog1.java(updated)

```
package programmes;
public class prog1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is program 1");
    }
}
```

prog2.java(updated)

```
package programmes;
public class prog2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("This is program 2");
    }
}
```

Then I wrote the following commands in terminal

```
>javac -d . *.java
>java prog1
```

Got error. Error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class prog1    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prog1
```

As per my knowledge java is not able to find the bytecode file of prog1 which is in package programmes.

Similarly I got the same error for program 2 (only one command as byte code file is already created)

```
java prog2
```

Error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class prog2    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: prog2
```

[Image of error faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAVhb.png)

I'm not able to get what I'm doing wrong here?
As jdk is properly installed because in the first scenario I'm able to get the output. Also I did add the address of jdk bin folder where java and javac files are present in the enviornment variables section in the path vairable before creating prog1.java and prog2.java files.

What else needs to be added or altered?

Comment: That should have been `java programmes.prog1` But class names begin upper case in Java

Comment: @g00se Thanks!, Now I got the output but my q is I wrote in the code ```package programmes;```  in the prog1.java file doesn't that mean java will automatically search the  in the package programmes for the prog1.class file?

Comment: *doesn't that mean java will automatically search the in the package programmes for the prog1.class file?* No. Just as, if you had a file system tree of source files a/X.java and b/X.java (representing packages 'a' and 'b') each X.java is not the same. Also the binaries of a/X.class and b/X.class could be quite different. How would the runtime know which one to address unless addressed by the f.q. package names of a.X and b.X

Answer (score 0):

You mix the concept of packages for structuring the source code and Java ARchives (JAR) for packaging compiled binaries.

Probably you want to put all your .class files into one java archive (extension is .jar) and with the right folder structure and "magic" file in there (called MANIFEST.MF) you can instruct java to run your `main` method from the commandline without knowing the actual class.

Java even comes with its own tool to create such files (effectively it's a ZIP file with conventions for the contents): `jar`

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24346087/2846138) you will find several ways described how you create such a file.

To find more (technical) details about the structure inside, you can also read the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) on the file format.

Finally when you have created your own jar-file, you will start it with a command line like `java -jar myprogram.jar`.